# spring data jpa on timestamp field for current date?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have to query on timestamp field for current date and get only 1 record. 
I can write the query like:

```
@Query("Select i From Log i Where i.createdBy = :userId And DATE(i.createdDate) = CURRENT_DATE")
```

**JPA Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log")
public class Log {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "log_id")
    private Long logId;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Calendar createdDate;

    //SETTERS AND GETTERS
}
```

**TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
    `log_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `address` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `created_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

here i am not able to limit the records, 
I know we can limit the records by sending Pageable, but again i have to get the record from list.

Is there any way to do this ?
how can we do it in spring data jpa method name ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Spring Data repository to do this like the following:

```
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Log, Long> {

  // just get one or null
  Log findOneByCreatedByAndCreatedDate(Instant createdBy, Instant createdDate);

  // get all, but pagable
  List<Log> findAllByCreatedByAndCreatedDate(Instant createdBy, Instant createdDate, Pageable pageable);

}
```

I assume you use `Instant` as timestamp, but this should also work for the other Java 8 date types or the old `Date` class.

Within your business logic you can now call:

```
Log log = logRepository.findOneByCreatedByAndCreatedDate(YOUR_TIMESTAMP, Instant.now());

// or
Log allLogs = logRepository.findOneByCreatedByAndCreatedDate(YOUR_TIMESTAMP, Instant.now(), PageRequest.of(0, 50));
```

Comment: i want to get the record on current date but the field is of timestamp. will it work ?

Comment: Got this exception: Parameter value [2019-02-22T20:17:06.463Z] did not match expected type [java.util.Calendar (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2019-02-22T20:17:06.463Z] did not match expected type [java.util.Calendar (n/a)].

Comment: can you update your question with your JPA entity Java class and the DDL script for the table?

Comment: i have updated the question with entity and table. please check

Comment: I am missing the `createdBy` column you are trying to access in the original `@Query` you posted. I wouldn't use `Calender` type within the entity. Replace is with `Instant` and remove the `@Temporal` and `@DateFormat` annotations

Comment: Parameter value [2020-07-09T21:00:00Z] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]